# how does appcompat library styling work

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat

I'm quite confused about how styling in appcompat library works.

According to [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/):

> We now use the support implementation of Toolbar/ActionBar on all
>   platforms meaning that we no longer read any android: attributes
>   related to the action bar.
>
> For apps which already have existing appcompat setups, this means that
>   you should remove your v14+ themes which re-set the same values in the
>   android namespace. Please note, this is ONLY applicable for
>   styles/widgets which affect the action bar.
>
> For most apps, you now only need one theme declaration, in values/

So here is my question:

If I want to use material design ActionBar in API 14+, I can just use ActionBar/Toolbar provided in appcompat_v7 and style it in the common value/ folder with the "android:" namespace removed ? but why am I seeing people writing code below:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ....
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    ....
</style>
```

why is "android:" namespace there? what's the difference between the code above and using value-v21, value-v14, folders?

can someone explain or direct me to the right source?

Comment: Are you using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)? This is not an official library. Anything said by Google may or may not be applicable to it.

Comment: @karaokyo I'm not, I'm just using an example of it

Comment: Then it probably just means that whatever code you're looking at is not using v21 of the support library.

Comment: @karaokyo so you mean if I use v21 support library then I don't need "android:" item?

Comment: That's not what that post says. It says that the appcompat library will not look to android namespaced attributes for action bar styles. ie. it should just be `app:windowContentOverlay` in your `values/` folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you use AppCompat v21+, you only need a single theme with a parent of `Theme.AppCompat` (or a subtheme such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light`) and you do **not** need the `android:` namespace attributes for action bar/window related flags, nor separate themes for v14, v20, etc. The full list of top level attributes which AppCompat provides across all API levels can be found in the [AppCompat R.styleable Theme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.styleable.html#Theme).

Much of the code on the internet (including parts of the developer.android.com site) are still written for the pre-v21 AppCompat, which *did* require both the `android:` and non-prefixed versions.

Comment: Thanks! that's quite helpful. But when I try to set for example `elevation` or `background` of appcompat actionbar without `android:`, it does not have any effect, could you explain why?

Comment: You should be using `colorPrimary` for coloring the action bar and `getSupportActionBar().setElevation()` for a backward compatible way to set the elevation - unfortunately, I don't know a way to set elevation via XML in a backward compatible way.