# Library or documentation of AppCompat Parent style in android

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm so confused designing my actionbar in android.
I'm using AppCompat theme, if anyone out there who knows a better documentation of the AppCompat Theme can you please share it?
API Level 19

Found one: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

**App Compat support lib**, don't worry about parent theme, its automatically set theme as per API level  [check answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29338831/1168654)
if you have device with API 19 then its set that theme which is available in API-19

for Action Bar(which is deprecated by ToolBar in API 21). but if you still want to use this then extends your `Activity` class to `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class myDemoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

in `onCreate()` use actionbar like:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

you have to use theme like

```
<style name="AppTheme.Bash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

---

**Toolbar**

extends your `Activity` class to `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class myDemoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

you have to use toolbar in your layout file like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in `onCreate()`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

you have to use theme like

```
<style name="AppTheme.Bash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
```